# Updating userform textboxes in userform frames

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to create a system within a VBA textbox that modifies the input.

Textboxes along with other options are in frames that can be opened and closed. Done to keep the form readable for other people.

I know it can be done by editing the string solely in code (and have done that to keep working on the project) but I want people to see the edits the code makes.

These updates are inconsistent. I have two textboxes that edit themselves with identical lines of code and they are both set to update themselves once the textbox has been exited. One only updates if something within the frame that it is in gets clicked on again and the other doesn't update at all whether clicking within its frame or outside.

Ideally the moment a textbox gets edited and something else gets clicked on the textbox updates.

**Update**
Only updates itself if something else like another checkbox in the frame is clicked or selected and it will also then work when clicking outside of the frame. Does anyone know why?

*Code for both*

```
Private Sub Pathbox_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Pathbox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim sDir As String
sDir = S5Int.Pathbox.Text
If Right(sDir, 1) <> "\" Then
     S5Int.Pathbox.Text = sDir & "\"
End If

End Sub
```

The same code for both except the name of the procedure. Frames are also same except for their names. In the form they look something like this:

*Form with textboxes*
[image: Form with the textboxes in question]

*Settings of the elements are also identical*
[image: Settings of frames][image: Settings of textboxes]

Comment: I believe you want to use Repaint on the form. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.repaint

Comment: Good suggestion, I tried it just now but Im getting the same inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Look at the occurrences of the events bearing in mind that there are frames as well as text boxes, both of which are form controls with their own events. The single click with which you move from one Tbx to another actually first triggers the Tbx's Exit, then the Frame's Enter, then the Frame' Exit, the other Frame's Enter and only then the other Tbx's Enter, with misc Change events on the way. I remember trying this once. Not all events occur as expected and I recall giving it up. In the end replacing the frames with labels in the background to have all controls on the same pane.

Comment: I do not see any text box on the picture you show us. Then, a `Change` event does  not exist for a frame. Otherwise, the code should work without problem when you exit the text object on the frame. What do you mean by frames "to be opened and closed"? Why don't you use the text box excel event, instead of the frame? Are they already used? If yes, you should post their events code, too.

Comment: @FaneDuru Their in the first image. Those white boxes within the frames. 

Also I changed the names of the textboxes.

Comment: Do you mean below the labels 'Label1' and 'Label2'? If yes, it looks like being placed on purpose to confuse us... :) So, do the text boxes in discussion have their own events used?

Comment: FaneDuru: Yes those, didnt write the labels yet :P
@Variatus Thanks you for the info; would it then be possible to somehow clear all triggers once executed then? I Also have the suspicion its to do with the exit procedure thats being used. An alternative would be a good idea to try out.

Comment: I've just played with two frames on a form, each of them having a text box and using **only the frames Exit event**, everything runs smooth, without any problem. I did not understand from your answer if the text boxes in discussion has their own events...

Comment: Yeah they have their own events, mostly to do with the contents of the textbox. The code you see are only for the textboxes but I could try executing the code referencing the frame. Actually that could be the solution gonna try that out now.

Comment: @FaneDuru How exactly did you get that to work? Referencing the frames with the exit event does even less.

Comment: Like I said, "using **only the frames Exit event**". But the text box in discussion do not have any event used. Try commenting their events (from testing purpose) and see what happens. It may be a conflict between the events. If you do not show them to us, we cannot understand what may happen.

Comment: @faneDuru It doesnt do anything if only write **Frame1_Exit (ByVal etc)** (rest of the sub) Does work but it doesnt update the textbox upon exiting the textbox (clicking away). Unless Im missing something.

Comment: "Clicking away" outside the frame in discussion, or on the frame? I would also suggest you to put a break point on the line `sDir = S5Int.Pathbox.Text` and then run the code line by line pressing F8, in order to see where the code goes after the frame event has been triggered and what wrong is happening there...

Comment: @FaneGuru Yeah did that works for the first textbox somewhat but it doesnt update the way I want to. That might just be the form not updating properly. The second textbox doesnt even execute even though vba has tied the exit procedure properly to the right textbox object. It just doesnt trigger it seems. VBA itself might be bugging out but I dont feel experienced enough to make that call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228854/discussion-between-sjoerd-and-faneduru).

Comment: I must leave now my office. The events are all the time triggered. You must check if you did not wrongly allocate the event to another Frame. Maybe behind the one you think it belongs...

Comment: Thanks for the help regardless. I checked that it isnt allocated to the wrong frame otherwise I would have realised that when hiding and disabling it. That works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution last week;**
I have just put the trigger of updating on the form itself whenever the form itself is clicked it runs through checks to see what needs to be updated and updates; Its a bit crude but it works quite well. This solution wont work if something else other than the form is clicked but that didnt work either for Textbox1_Exit(etc). Since it only updates the form when the form is in the forefront.

It is Also a bit wasteful of cycles as it runs every single time anything on the form is clicked too but as long as the checks are efficient it should be good enough.

I will keep working on a better solution however when I have time, maybe see if I can get exiting from the frame working like FaneDuru said but something else on the form seems to be blocking that solution for now.